# Realm database issue. -No default Realm Configuration was found-

Tags: java, android, realm

This is my model class for my reminds

```
public class Remind extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    private String descripcion;
    @Required
    private String fecha;
    @Required
    private String hora;
    @Required
    private String titulo;
    @PrimaryKey
   private String id;

   public Remind() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getHora() {
        return hora;
    }
    public void setHora(String hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }
}
```

this is my config class for obtain context 'cause i don't know what is the
problem with this class :(

```
public class RemindMe extends Application {

    @RealmModule(classes = {Remind.class})
    public class SimpleRealmModule {}
    private static RemindMe instance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).name("RemindMe.DB").build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

and this is a part of mi DAO for add some reminds

//this is so problematic class 'cause the Realm object don't find the
database context

```
public class RemindsDAO {

   static boolean flag = false;

    public boolean agregarRecordatorio(final Remind remind){
            final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    Remind rem = realm.createObject(Remind.class);
                    rem.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    rem.setTitulo(remind.getTitulo());
                    rem.setDescripcion(remind.getDescripcion());
                    rem.setHora(remind.getHora());
                    rem.setFecha(remind.getFecha());
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                     RemindsDAO.flag = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                     flag = false;
                }
            });

        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `Realm.getDefaultInstance` some where? If you do, `Realm.getInstance(RemindMe.getInstance());` will throw, since you are give two different Realm with different configurations but the same name and path.

Comment: i can't understand you, i need to declare a default instance for my realm ?

Comment: But you have already done it `RemindMe.onCreate()`. Where does the exception throw and what is the exception message?

Comment: first the error message was in IllegalAplicationContext right in Realm object instance, before i tried to fix it , right in the line  realm.beginTransaction(); and the exception this time is NullPointer

Comment: I guess your `RemindMe` is not registered as the default application and `RemindMe.onCreate` is not run, you can set a breakpoint to verify that. Take a look of http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/ . You need to register the `RemindMe` in the manifest.

Comment: it works bro :D, thank you a lot but i have another question, how can i do for create a method with boolean return with realm, kind of web app in a CRUD

Comment: I don't really get your question. What do you want the method to do?

Comment: return a boolean value in the method

Comment: With current release (0.87.5), you can add a static method to the your RealmObject. But with the next release (0.88.0) which will be released very soon, you can freely define your own member method. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2196 and you can try it out with Realm's snapshot release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register your Application class in the Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".RemindMe">
   your activities go here...
</application>
```

Once done you should be able to use Realm.getDefaultInstance() throughout the app with no hassle.